# Почему в методе main() аргумент массива строк традиционно называется "args"?

Tags: java, c, массивы, jvm, main

Почему в методе main в языке `C` в роле аргументов принимаются `argc` и `argv`, а в `Java` - `args`? Как расшифровывается эта короткая форма или почему она именно такая?

Comment: Как минимум это слово в том же смысле встречается ещё в книге «Язык программирования Си» 1978 года выпуска: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTdZD.png

Comment: @andreymal, разве не `argv`?

Comment: @avp а там рядышком есть и args :)

Comment: ну окей, почему тогда, С args? это ведь не объясняет вопрос

Comment: Я, конечно, не эксперт, но может быть потому что это аргументы, а по английски это будет arguments, а args просто удобное сокращение?

Comment: С `args` понятно, а почему тогда в добавок у C по ссылке из первого комментария присутствует `argv` ?

Comment: @Axel23 в той же книжке расшифровывают как arguments vector. А почему vector, не знаю, в книжке не рассказывают

Comment: Какое ещё "традиционно `args`"? Аргументы `main` традиционно называются `argc` и `argv`. Никакого `args`.

Comment: @AnT , в Inteliji автоматически всегда пишется так `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: @AnT и почему тогда `argc` и `argv` имеют такие названия?

Comment: @Axel23, скорее всего: `argc — arguments count`, `argv — arguments value's`, в то время `args — arguments strings`

Comment: `args` - это просто множественное число от сокращенного `arg`. Никакие "strings"  тут ни при чем. Просто если единственное число - `arg` , то, по правилам английского языка, множественное число - `args`. Точно также вы можете встретить `vals` вместо `values`, `funcs` вместо `functions`, `chars` вместо `characters` и т.п.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В C аргументы назывались `argc` и `argv` как сокращения от: `argument count` и `argument vector`. Да да, именно `vector`. Вас может это удивить, потому что векторы в C еще не существовали, когда C придумывался, однако этому есть объяснение. Все дело в том, что когда K&R придумывали C были уже другие языки, такие известные, как [Algol 68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68), так вот там уже использовали термин `vector`:

> bits - a "packed vector" of bool.
>   bytes - a "packed vector" of char.

Потому что раньше одномерный массив и вектор у математиков были синонимами, а программисты тогда были в основном математиками. Поэтому суффикс `v` прижился как `vector` в именах переменных. K&R просто сделали так, потому что это уже было в других языках.

[Оригинальный ответ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/196666/337795)

Теперь вернемся к Java. Мы знаем, что когда создавалась Java, то на рынке программистов большинство знало C/C++, поэтому чтобы сделать переход к Java тех программистов, которые уже писали на C, более легким, в Java изначально было сделано много языковых конструкций, которые были похожи на C. Много соглашений о коде были похожи на C. Как мне кажется, это в той или иной мере коснулось и имени параметра `args`. Поскольку `argc` для Java уже не имел смысла, так как размер массива в Java хранится в объекте массива, то достаточно было одного аргумента. Однако `argv` [в C] в себе на первом месте хранит название программы, а в Java `args` в себе на первом месте хранит первый аргумент, то есть если бы использовали `argv` - это могло бы запутать начинающих Java программистов. Поэтому, как мне кажется, `args` больше всего подходило, так как это:

- не `agrv`, структура хранения параметров немного иная
- короткое название для аргументов (`arg`ument`s`), прямо как в старом добром C/C++

Comment: Да, а сейчас *"программисты"* в основном малообразованные PHP кодеры...